# Updating context menu depending on the clicked link in a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want the text of a context menu item to depend on the URL/text of the link it was opened for. Firefox WebExtensions API has [`menus.onShown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/onShown) exactly for this, but it [currently isn't available in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus). Is there some workaround?

Comment: You can try to detect the active element with a content script. If you store that somewhere when it's an A tag (or IMG?), you can use that to update the context menu item before it's shown.

Comment: There are several answers here on StackOverflow that show how to make a dynamic context menu based on clicked element.

Comment: For example, this one seems to be almost exactly what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202896/creating-dynamic-context-menu-in-chrome-extension-is-failing